# Python installation doesn't support type of template loading

Tags: django, frameworks, boilerplate

I've installed `Aldryn-boilerplates`, using `Configuration` block's advices from github (https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-boilerplates#configuration). 
But when I make `python manage.py runserver` I recieve a message:

```
/home/stp/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py:110: UserWarning: Your TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting includes'aldryn_boilerplates.template_loaders.AppDirectoriesLoader', but your Python installation doesn't support that type of template loading. Consider removing that line from TEMPLATE_LOADERS.
  warnings.warn("Your TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting includes %r, but your Python installation doesn't support that type of template loading. Consider removing that line from TEMPLATE_LOADERS." % loader)
```

The web page loads normally (without any template or style).

Also a question, where to put line `ALDRYN_BOILERPLATE_NAME = 'bootstrap3'`? I've placed it in the bottom of my project's `settings.py` file.

Anyone knows how to fix that? Or maybe there are another framework with much more detailed description about installation and configuration, which fits for beginners?

Comment: I've stopped development using Django right now. I don't have enough experience and knowledges in Python to create smooth web-pages.

Answer (score 1):

I got the some error with django 1.8 and a custom template loader. I had overridden the Loader class out of django.templates.loaders.base. To get rid of this error I also had to the set the class variable is_usable to true

```
class Myloader(Loader):
    is_usable = True
```

So maybe you can solve your issue with subclassing the  'aldryn_boilerplates.template_loaders.AppDirectoriesLoader' and only change the class variable as shown above.

Answer (score -1):

You have placed the `ALDRYN_BOILERPLATE_NAME = 'bootstrap3'` at the right place. Please mention the versions of python and django-cms you are using. If you want to try another blogging platform for python, then http://mezzanine.jupo.org/ is helpful for beginners, because it's very easy to setup.